# CSS a:hover color doesn't show in ie 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, hyperlink, hover

Please have a look at http://pang.it/pezzella/template.html. The links should be red on hover. Works great in FF, Opera & Chrome, but not in IE8. I just can't understand the reason. Changing `a:link` to `text-decoration:underline` gives the underline in red on hover but not the link text. Is this a bug or did I miss out on something in my css?

part of the css:

```
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

.linkGrey01{ color:#ddd; }
.linkGrey02{ color:#bbb; }
.linkGrey03{ color:#999; }
.linkGrey04{ color:#777; }
.linkGrey05{ color:#555; }
.linkGrey06{ color:#000; }

a:hover{
    color:#f00;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine in IE8: http://i.imgur.com/kNFZX.png

Comment: have you tried using the IE Developer Tools? Press F12 in IE8 to bring it up. It should help you work out what styles are being applied.

Comment: Yes I've tried  the IE Developer Tools. It didn't give me any usefull information. There is no style with the color blue!

Answer (score 2):

It looks correct to me in IE8. I noticed that you didn't style `a:visited`, that could be your problem.

Comment: Looks fine for me too (IE8 under Windows 7 64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.

I am guessing the issue has to do with the css specificity.  The :hover is applying a color to the anchor tag.  The same anchor tag has a class  (.linkGrey01, .linkGrey02.... etc)  which also apply a color.  classes trump tags in specificity.

Perhaps try

```
.linkGrey01 a:hover,
.linkGrey02 a:hover,
...etc....
.linkGrey06 a:hover {
    color:#f00;
}
```

[Here's a good tid-bit on CSS specificity](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/understanding_c/).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure about this: My links get blue on hover and there is absoluteley no place where I've defined the color as blue, or am I wrong? So it's likely not a problem of specificity. I also tried to change IE's properties to use other colors as green or black on hover but my links are still blue.

Comment: That's a puzzler.   There is no reference to blue in the CSS.  Did you once have a CSS that had blue in it and it got cached in the browser?

Comment: No and of course I've cleaned the cache but I found the solution. Sorry that I can't explain why: I removed Helvetica narrow and Helvetica from the body css and things turned out right. IE is strange!

Answer (score 0):

I can't say how great you all have been taking the time to answer. I do hope I can be of help to someone here. :-)

I finally found a solution, but I can't explain why it worked. What I did, 
was to change:

```
body {
font-family: Helvetica Narrow,  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
```

to read:

```
body {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;}
```

and voialà.

I would like to know why Helvetica created this problem though... Anyone?

Answer (score -1):

Or try `color:#F00 !important;`, but I think @nkorth was right.

Comment: I've tried both but with the same result. So it seems to be a problem with my browser. I'm happy to hear it. I've been working on this for more than an hour and really going crazy. Thanks a lot!